# Counter functions does not build upon previously returned value

Tags: c++, constructor, while-loop, counter

The first if statement enters as suspected. The object calls the getCount() function but the value that is incremented is not the previous count but instead 0. I tried using Count += Count in the function.

```
int main(){
    .........     
    int displayCount;
    while(!inputfile.eof()) 
    {

        inputfile.get(letter);

            Checker object1;
            if (object1.isValid(letter)))
            {
                displayCount = object1.getCount();
            }
    }
    cout << displayCount;
   .
   .
   .
Checker::Checker() :
    m_Valid(false),
    count(0)
{
}


int Checker::getCount()
{

    if(m_Valid)
    {
        count ++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

My inclination is that once the value is returned from the function then thats it. It will no longer hold the previous value bc of this (my guess).

Comment: [Please don't use `eof()` in the loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: `m_Valid(false)` then `if(m_Valid)` always return false?

Comment: Billz, it doesn't always return false because I have a seperate function that returns true when applicable. I stepped through the code and that if statment returns true as expected.

Comment: In the header file, it is declared as a private accessor as "int count"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to move `Checker object1` outside of the loop; a new instance is being created with a count of zero for each pass as the code stands.

Answer (score 0):

As your comment, `count` is not staic member of Check class, `Checker object1;` always creates a new object and initialize count to `0`.  make count static should make your `getCount()` rolling.

```
class Checker
{
   static int count;
};
```

initialize count in Checker.cpp

```
int Check::count = 0;
```

Comment: If you don't need to dynamically create `object1`, the other answer is better than mine.

Comment: I don't need to do it dynamically, but I tried your way. It worked as well. Thanks!